# Printing stdout (print) commands to tkinter window with .pyw extension

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, stdout

I am making a Python (3) GUI Program with tkinter, and I am using a redirect function to direct all my print statements to a GUI Scrolled text box.

This is the redirect function (in the same class as the tkinter window):

```
def redirector(self,inputStr):
    self.txt.insert(tk.INSERT, inputStr)
    self.txt.update()
    self.txt.see(tk.END)
```

And then I add this line when I want to start redirecting the output:

```
sys.stdout.write = self.redirector
```

But when I rename the file to .pyw, nothing appears on the textbox. Please suggest a method to correctly direct the text to the GUI Window.

Comment: you mean it works when you call your file `.py` right?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes it does.

Comment: Please revised answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why your print calls aren't working is because when you run a `.pyw` file on Windows, the executable that runs your program is actually `pythonw.exe`, which internally initializes your application by calling [WinMain()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms633559(v=vs.85).aspx), and so doesn't create a console. No console means no standard IO streams, thus `sys.stdout` is undefined.

Instead, I suggest you subclass `tk.Text` and define the `write()` and `flush()` functions as  instance methods. Then all you have to do is set `sys.stdout` to your subclass instance and everything should work.

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk


class TextOut(tk.Text):

    def write(self, s):
        self.insert(tk.CURRENT, s)

    def flush(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    text = TextOut(root)
    sys.stdout = text
    text.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I need to implement this in my program, in which the tkinter window is running through the class called App(). How do I do this? Sorry I'm really new to Python.

Comment: @NikhilRamakrishnan Please, share a link to your full code.

Comment: @NikhilRamakrishnan [Here](http://pastebin.com/RGGb0QFC) is my idea applied to your code. If it works, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: I am trying to understand the code, and please correct me if I am wrong. What you did was make the sub-class `ScrolledTextOut` and (re)defined the `write` and `flush` functions (from `stdout`) in it. `txt` now is a `ScrolledTextOut`. The `sys.stdout = self.txt` redirects print statements to `ScrolledTextOut` and the `write` function does rest of the job. Am I right?

Comment: @NikhilRamakrishnan That's it :)